# Operation Contract Definition Causes Windows Service to Not Respond to Control Function

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, service

I've been developing a windows service with a WCF service hosted within it. Throughout development I've been able install and start my service successfully, testing features as I added them. However, I've recently added a method to my Service Contract:

```
[OperationContract]
void StartWebsiteProcessing(WebsiteInfo info);
```

This method, when called by a WCF client calls this method:

```
public void StartWebsiteProcessing(WebsiteInfo info)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(this.AddWebsite);
    t.Start(info);
}
```

Now, after I install the service, when I go to start the service I receive this message:

"The service is not responding to the control function."

From there I went about undoing the changes I had made one by one trying to determine what was causing this. I discovered that if I remove the StartWebsiteProcessing method from the service contract I can successfully start the service again.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: Does WebsiteInfo have the required DataContract/DataMember annotations?

Comment: Since I don't know what those are I guess not. Can you explain this to me?

Comment: If you have complex types (i.e. classes or structs) as parameters or return values, you need to tell the serializer how to handle them. The class itself needs to have a [DataContract] attribute and all data members need a [DataMember] attribute, just like you have [ServiceContract] and [OperationContract] for your service. If you open a new, default WCFService1 Project in Visual Studio, take a look at the example complex type that's used there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
void StartWebsiteProcessing(WebsiteInfo info);
```